# Determine if a polygon is convex

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, decision-problem

Write a program to determine if the input polygon is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons).  The polygon is specified with one line containing *N*, the number of vertices, then *N* lines containing the *x* and *y* coordinates of each vertex.  The vertices will be listed clockwise starting from an arbitrary vertex.

### example 1

#### input

```
4
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 0
```

#### output

```
convex
```

### example 2

#### input

```
4
0 0
2 1
1 0
2 -1
```

#### output

```
concave
```

### example 3

#### input

```
8
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
2 1
2 0
1 0
```

#### output

```
convex
```

*x* and *y* are integers, *N<1000*, and *|x|,|y|<1000*.  You may assume that the input polygon is simple (none of the edges cross, only 2 edges touch each vertex).  Shortest program wins.

Comment: "Simple" doesn't include "consecutive edges are non-collinear"?!

Also, a couple more test-cases: (0,0) (0,2) (2,2) (2,0) (1,1); and (1,1) (0,0) (0,2) (2,2) (2,0) - to test the cases where finding the concave vertex requires wrapping from the end back to the start.

Comment: This question is aging, but... Consider adding a concave example with two aligned segments, e.g. a modification of example 2:
(0,0),(2,1),(4,2),(1,0)(2,-1). I bring this up because I fudged around example 3 without realizing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## J, 105

```
echo>('concave';'convex'){~1=#=(o.1)([:>-.~)(o.2)|3([:-/12 o.-@-/@}.,-/@}:)\(,2&{.)j./"1}.0&".;._2(1!:1)3
```

Passes all three tests above.

**Edit:** (111->115) Handle co-linear points by eliminating angles of pi. Gained a few characters elsewhere.

**Edit:** (115->105) Less dumb.

Explanation for the J-impaired:

- `(1!:1)3` read STDIN to EOF. (I think.)
- `0&".;._2` is a nice idiom for parsing this kind of input.
- `j./"1}.` lop off first line of input (N 0) and convert pairs to complexes.
- `(,2&{.)` tack first two points onto the end of the list.
- `3(f)\` applies f to  sliding window of length 3 (3 points for  an angle)
- `[:-/12 o.-@-/@}.,-/@}:` is a verb that transforms each 3 points into an angle between -pi and pi.

  - `-@-/@}.,-/@}:` produces (p1 - p2),(p3 - p2). (Recall that these are complexes.)
  - `12 o.` gives an angle for each complex.
  - `[:-/(...)` gives the difference of the two angles.
- `(o.1)([:>-.~)(o.2)|` mod 2 pi, eliminate angles of pi (straight segments), and compare to pi (greater than, less than, doesn't matter unless the points are supposed to be wound in one direction).
- `1=#=` if all those comparison result 1 or 0 (With self-classify. This seems dumb.)
- `echo>('concave';'convex'){~` print convex.

Answer (score 3):

### Python - 149 chars

```
p=[map(int,raw_input().split())for i in[0]*input()]*2
print'ccoonncvaevxe'[all((a-c)*(d-f)<=(b-d)*(c-e)for(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)in zip(p,p[1:],p[2:]))::2]
```

Comment: I think you need <=, see example 3 I just added.

Comment: dammn, that slice...

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9, <strike>147</strike> <strike>133</strike> <strike>130</strike> <strike>124</strike> 123

```
gets
puts ($<.map{|s|s.split.map &:to_i}*2).each_cons(3).any?{|(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)|(e-c)*(d-b)<(d-f)*(a-c)}?:concave: :convex
```

Answer (score 1):

#### scala: 297 chars

```
object C{class D(val x:Int,val y:Int)
def k(a:D,b:D,c:D)=(b.y-a.y)*(c.x-b.x)>=(c.y-b.y)*(b.x-a.x) 
def main(a:Array[String]){val s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
def n=s.nextInt
val d=for(x<-1 to n)yield{new D(n,n)}print((true/:(d:+d.head).sliding(3,1).toList)((b,t)=>b&&k(t(0),t(1),t(2))))}}
```

Comment: You can shave of three chars by using `def main(a:...` instead of `def main(args:...`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed myself, but 299 to 149 doesn't bring me in the area of someone else. Maybe if I find other improvements - ah, there is one: n is a function name (next) and a variable name.